# Guava Cache - what is the implication of comparing values by identity

Tags: java, guava

The `CacheBuilder` methods `weakValues()` and `softValues()` both contain this line in their javadocs:

> Note: when this method is used, the resulting cache will use identity (==) comparison to determine equality of values.

How exactly does this affect behaviour? As far as I can tell there are no public methods on the `Cache` or `LoadingCache` interface which would require testing for value equality. Does it affect the `asMap()` view?

Comment: I guess this concerns mostly the maps view and maybe future extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it uses Google's `ConcurrentMap` internally and uses value comparison for `remove` and `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

**Guava** internally caches those **soft/weak** values. If the reference of 2 weak/soft values are equal then the content must be equal too.

**Guava** only compares those values in methods like **contains(...)**, **remove(...)** or **replace(...)** and is used to find a specifc entry and check if it really exists or to remove a key. So guava first looks for the **specific** entry. If found it removes the entry.

I think the main purpose is to **detect** an excplicit removal of an entry, because if the value,  which the reference points to is already **null**, then it was not an **explicit** removal, but it was removed by guava internally (**computed**).

It's nothing to worry about. It's just the way guava handles the removal of old entries.

There is no way to change this and you really don't have to care about this, guava will handle this :D